# Showing Access Level in Class Diagram

Tags: oop, uml, class-diagram

I am having an assignment to create a class diagram for a certain software. Now, I identified the important classes and linked them and they are fine.

The thing is that I am having two different classes associated with another same class, but with different access level. For instance, I am having `Admin` and `Clerk` classes associated with `Video` class. The `Clerk` will be able to only view, whilst `Admin` is able to view and edit. Can I show this distinction in Class Diagram?

Comment: I would think such *implementation details* are beyond the scope of a class diagram, no?

Comment: @retailcoder That is what I think also, but not quite sure. I though there might be something and I didn't now about it.

Comment: You normally should not display this in a class diagram, but you could depending on how it is modeled.  If the Admin and Clerks both have methods which accept the Video that is to be acted upon, then the presence/absence of the relevant methods in those objects could express their permissions.  This could further be defined using interfaces which represent the permissions which are implemented by the appropriate actors.  I'd prefer going more of the AOP route for this type of authorization if that's more in line with the business logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can show this on a class diagram, if, in fact, the classes are part of the *problem domain*. If you are modeling these classes as part of the *solution domain*, then you should not. For more on this topic, please read the excellent article by Leon Starr, called [How to Build Articulate Class Models and get 
Real Beneﬁts from UML](http://www.uml.org/HTB_Articulate_Class_Models_OMG.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

If *Admin* and *Clerk* are classes (and not actors), you cloud use something like [GenMyModel http://app.genmymodel.com/engine/xaelis/accessLevel.jpg](http://app.genmymodel.com/engine/xaelis/accessLevel.jpg)